# How to request shopify graphql-admin-api from an api?

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am trying to request shopify graphql-admin-api from my api. I am doing it according to the documentation given by graphql-admin-api, but it still gives me authorization errors.

Comment: Can you add code example of what you are doing and what values you are passing?

Comment: authorization errors mean your access token isn't correct

Comment: @TrầnTrịnhKuy i am doing it according to the documentation

Comment: After R&D my findings are that to request shopify-graphql-admin-api you needs to request from a server (server-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

PHP users can follow this function to make request to Shopify Admin API using GraphQL

I am using GuzzleHttp ( PHP HTTP client ) to create request

```
public function graph($query , $variables = []){
    $domain = 'xxx.myshopify.com';
    $url = 'https://'.$domain.'/admin/api/2019-10/graphql.json';

    $request = ['query' => $query];

    if(count($variables) > 0) { $request['variables'] = $variables; }

    $req = json_encode($request);
    $parameters['body'] = $req;

    $stack = HandlerStack::create();
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'handler'  => $stack,
        'headers'  => [
            'Accept'       => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token'=>$this->token // shopify app accessToken
        ],
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('post',$url,$parameters);
    return $body =  json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
 }

  $query = "{ shop { name email } }"; // this is example graphQL query

  $response = graph($query) // call this function
```

Below code can help you to check how much cost this graphQL query

```
$calls = $response->extensions->cost;
$apiCallLimitGraph = [
     'left'          => (int) $calls->throttleStatus->currentlyAvailable,
     'made'          => (int) ($calls->throttleStatus->maximumAvailable - $calls->throttleStatus->currentlyAvailable),
     'limit'         => (int) $calls->throttleStatus->maximumAvailable,
     'restoreRate'   => (int) $calls->throttleStatus->restoreRate,
     'requestedCost' => (int) $calls->requestedQueryCost,
     'actualCost'    => (int) $calls->actualQueryCost,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Apps -> Manage Apps at the bottom and then :
Create a private app in Shopify, which will connect to your application. Make sure you manage permission for what you want to query

After creating the private app you will get the password which you can use as the token for your HTTP requests with **header** 'X-Shopify-Access-Token' **value**: password

```
  curl -X POST \
  https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/graphql.json \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/graphql' \
  -H 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: {password}' \
  -d '
  {
    products(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          handle
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
  '
```

For more visit: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/getting-started#authentication

The way I use in NodeJS is by using package **"graphql-request"** to make requests and

```
const mutation = gql`
      mutation createProduct(
        $input: ProductInput!
        $media: [CreateMediaInput!]
      ) {
        productCreate(input: $input, media: $media) {
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
          product {
            id
            metafields(first: 1) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;
     //const input = form your own input 
     const res = await graphQLClient.rawRequest(mutation, input);
```

Comment: Is this secure since it is HTTP? Is there an alternative way such as creating custom app?