# New order email need to send particular email address

Tags: email, shopify

Hi every one i am new to shopify. I have created one website by using shopify. Now i am stuck at one issue. I need an email to be sent to one email address  when customer places an order on the site for a one particular product A. It won’t get sent to Sureship also. Can you help configure that?

Answer (score 1):

This is just possible by creating an APP.

Setup [shopify private app](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps)

1. create [webhook](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook) for topic orders/create.
2. Now whenever order will be created shopify will send order data to your predefined endpoint via webhook
3. you just need to check if this product is exist in received order data. if yes you can create custom email and send with details.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Do you have any sample code ? i have new in shopfiy

Comment: which is your prefered programming language ?

Comment: You need to refer Shopify documentation on how private app works, this code can help you to make API Calls with rest api with PHP => 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801924/how-to-create-pagination-in-shopify-rest-api-using-php/58412944#58412944

Comment: yes, all your PHP related stuff will go there in private APP