# Bad Request: Shopify pagination

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination, shopify

I would like to ask about shopify pagination version 2020-01

First request query:
URL: `https://klevarange.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?fulfillment_status=unfulfilled&limit=250&financial_status=paid&created_at_min=2019-08-27T16:15:47-04:00`

Return Header:

```
"<https://klevarange.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?limit=250&page_info=eyJmaW5hbmNpYWxfc3RhdHVzIjoicGFpZCIsImZ1bGZpbGxtZW50X3N0YXR1cyI6InVuZnVsZmlsbGVkIiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdF9taW4iOiIyMDE5LTA4LTI3IDIwOjE1OjQ3IFVUQyIsImxhc3RfaWQiOjIxMDQ4NzIxNzM2NTIsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiIyMDIwLTAyLTI3IDAwOjA5OjUyIiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCJ9>; rel=\"next\""
```

2nd Request Query:

```
"https://klevarange.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?limit=250&page_info=eyJmaW5hbmNpYWxfc3RhdHVzIjoicGFpZCIsImZ1bGZpbGxtZW50X3N0YXR1cyI6InVuZnVsZmlsbGVkIiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdF9taW4iOiIyMDE5LTA4LTI3IDIwOjE1OjQ3IFVUQyIsImxhc3RfaWQiOjIxMDQ4NzI1MzQxMDAsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiIyMDIwLTAyLTI3IDAwOjEwOjA3IiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCJ9>; rel=\"next\""
```

Result: Bad Request

What should I put in `page_info`? Do I need to include the `rel=\"next\""` in the page_info?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove **>** from your page_info variable

```
var page_info = "eyJmaW5hbmNpYWxfc3RhdHVzIjoicGFpZCIsImZ1bGZpbGxtZW50X3N0YXR1cyI6InVuZnVsZmlsbGVkIiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdF9taW4iOiIyMDE5LTA4LTI3IDIwOjE1OjQ3IFVUQyIsImxhc3RfaWQiOjIxMDQ4NzI1MzQxMDAsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiIyMDIwLTAyLTI3IDAwOjEwOjA3IiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCJ9"
```

and Make your request URL like below.

> https://klevarange.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?limit=250&page_info={page_info}

**Digging Deeper**

You need to iterate your while loop until there is no **Link** Parameter in the response header and this parameter is not a static value it is the address of last object you get and saying next will give you next 250 objects.

you need to update your pageInfo parameter in every request with newly generated next reference ( pageInfo )

[image]

When you do not get this parameter that means there is no next or previous page .

Have a look in this below code...( written in php )

[How to create pagination in shopify rest api using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57801924/how-to-create-pagination-in-shopify-rest-api-using-php/58412944#58412944)

Comment: This works no more bad request however after the 2nd query, results of some of the next query are orders from the first 2 queries. Therefore even though there are 1000 orders, it will become 5K orders due to repeating orders every query. Have you encountered similar issue?

Comment: You should not use `&rel=next` query parameter - it will be ignored. When you use `page_info=xxx` parameter - you can also pass `limit` and/or `fields` parameters along with it - all other parameters are not taken into account.

Comment: Yes, seems I mess up concept between rest API and graphQLAPI where we always need to pass  first / last & before/after for cursor based pagination..... and I have stopped using Rest API... thanks  @ Vladimir for drawing attention & example has been updated

Answer (score 1):

You should use only this part: `https://klevarange.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json?limit=250&page_info=eyJmaW5hbmNpYWxfc3RhdHVzIjoicGFpZCIsImZ1bGZpbGxtZW50X3N0YXR1cyI6InVuZnVsZmlsbGVkIiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdF9taW4iOiIyMDE5LTA4LTI3IDIwOjE1OjQ3IFVUQyIsImxhc3RfaWQiOjIxMDQ4NzI1MzQxMDAsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiIyMDIwLTAyLTI3IDAwOjEwOjA3IiwiZGlyZWN0aW9uIjoibmV4dCJ9` i.e. without `rel="next"`

In the 2nd and all next requests, you can only pass up to 3 query parameters:

- `page_info`
- `limit`
- `fields`

So if you want to get results from the next page you need to extract `page_info` value from the first response headers.

The idea is that you can move only forward or backwards while requesting the results and you can get the link (page_info token) to the next (or previous) page only after retrieving the current page results.

Comment: Hi, thank you. This works no more bad request however I noticed that the return orders keep repeating to the previous one. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Just to clarify, if the store contains 1000 orders and this will be 4 queries? Should I only used the first response header for page_info? As I noticed page_info changed every in every call.

Comment: @Jen143 You should get value from the `page_info` parameter after every request and use to get results from the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the last 2 years, Shopify has made some modifications to their API, then I use `GetNextPageFilter` method. This is my approach.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> ProductsGetList(string shopUrl, string accessToken)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>();
        var service = new ProductService(shopUrl, accessToken);

        var filter = GetFilters(shopUrl);
        var productList = await service.ListAsync(filter);

        if (productList != null && productList.Items.Any())
        {
            products.AddRange(productList.Items);
            bool hasMorePages = productList.HasNextPage;
            if (hasMorePages)
            {
                do
                {
                    var filterList = productList.GetNextPageFilter(filter.Limit, filter.Fields);
                    productList = await service.ListAsync(filterList);

                    if (productList != null && productList.Items.Any())
                    {
                        products.AddRange(productList.Items);
                        hasMorePages = productList.HasNextPage;
                    }
                } while (hasMorePages);
            }

        }


        return products;
    }

private ProductListFilter GetFilters(string url)
    {
        ProductListFilter filters = new ProductListFilter();

        string queryString = new System.Uri(url).Query;
        var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

        foreach (var parameter in queryDictionary)
        {
            var key = (string)parameter;
            var value = queryDictionary.Get(key);
            switch (key)
            {
                case "published_status":
                    filters.PublishedStatus = value;
                    break;
                case "published_at_max":
                    filters.PublishedAtMax = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value); 
                    break;
                case "published_at_min":
                    filters.PublishedAtMin = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "updated_at_max":
                    filters.UpdatedAtMax = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "updated_at_min":
                    filters.UpdatedAtMin = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "created_at_max":
                    filters.CreatedAtMax = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "presentment_currencies":
                    filters.PresentmentCurrencies = value.Split(',').AsEnumerable();
                    break;
                case "created_at_min":
                    filters.CreatedAtMin = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "status":
                    filters.Status = value;
                    break;
                case "product_type":
                    filters.ProductType = value;
                    break;
                case "handle":
                    filters.Handle = value; 
                    break;
                case "vendor":
                    filters.Vendor = value;
                    break;
                case "title":
                    filters.Title = value;
                    break;
                case "since_id":
                    filters.SinceId = long.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "collection_id":
                    filters.CollectionId = long.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case "ids":
                    filters.Ids = value.Split(',').AsEnumerable().Cast<long>();
                    break;
                case "limit":
                    filters.Limit = int.Parse(value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return filters;
    }
```

Where `shopUrl` is the entire URL (https://{apiKey}:{password}@{hostname}/admin/api/{version}/{resource}.json) and `accessToken` is the URL {password} atribute